# Will there be a 2012 moderator election?

Tags: discussion, election

Will there be a community [moderator election](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election/1) for CrossValidated this year?

(I'm asking out of curiosity. I think that the current moderators do a great job! :)

Comment: Do you think we need more moderators?

Comment: @whuber: No, from what I can see three (at least the current three) certainly seems to be enough. But as I understand it, there should be regular elections... right? Who decides when we have these?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SE powers-that-be make those decisions.

I don't know their policy, but Jeff Atwood, in his role as an SE representative, [asked a similar question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/984) three years ago.  It, and the ensuing replies, are part of the SE FAQ, so presumably it's a good guide as to what to expect.  Although it's not conclusive about the meaning of "regular elections," on the whole, "regular" looks like it depends on the community's size and rate of growth.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I wanted to know. :)